# Solr query to maintain order of terms in response as per query

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am working on **Solr** and have one query where I get some names which are in certain order and need to return associated data for those names in same order in which it came in query.

This is not a typical Solr query? so problem happens Solr so scoring while returning objects as per score calculation.
I need to maintain the order of these term in same order they came in query regardless of score.

Comment: Can you expand your example, because it is not clear how you get the 'associated data' and whether those 'names' are present in whatever you are retrieving finally.

Comment: I am retrieving link associated with name in that document

Comment: This still makes no sense really. Can you show a Solr query and data layout/schema? Otherwise, this question is just too broad.

Comment: How many names are we talking? Usually you can implement this by adding a large boost to each term - where the boost is dependent on the sequence you want to return (i.e. `term1^50000 term2^40000` etc.). By using `fq` for your query the query won't affect the score either.